# How to extract string that contains specific characters in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract ONLY one string that contains $ character. The input based on output that I extracted using BeautifulSoup.

Code

```
price = [m.split() for m in re.findall(r"\w+/$(?:\s+\w+/$)*", soup_content.find('blockquote', { "class": "postcontent restore" }).text)]
```

Input

```
For Sale is my Tag Heuer Carrera Calibre 6 with box and papers and extras.
39mm
47 ish lug to lug
19mm in between lugs
Pretty thin but not sure exact height. Likely around 12mm (maybe less)
I've owned it for about 2 years. I absolutely love the case on this watch. It fits my wrist and sits better than any other watch I've ever owned. I'm selling because I need cash and other pieces have more sentimental value
I am the second owner, but the first barely wore it.
It comes with barely worn blue leather strap, extra suede strap that matches just about perfectly and I'll include a blue Barton Band Elite Silicone.
I also purchased an OEM bracelet that I personally think takes the watch to a new level. This model never came with a bracelet and it was several hundred $ to purchase after the fact.
The watch was worn in rotation and never dropped or knocked around.
The watch does have hairlines, but they nearly all superficial. A bit of time with a cape cod cloth would take care of a lot it them. The pics show the imperfections in at "worst" possible angle to show the nature of scratches.
The bracelet has a few desk diving marks, but all in all, the watch and bracelet are in very good shape.
Asking $2000 obo. PayPal shipped. CONUS.
It's a big hard to compare with others for sale as this one includes the bracelet.
```

The output should be like this.

```
2000
```

Comment: There are 2 occurs of '$' in your input

Comment: `\S*\$\S*` might work, but will match the single `$` as well

Comment: I recommend writing a regular expression (you can use https://regex101.com/ to demo one) and then using python's `re` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex. Instead you can iterate over lines and over each word to check for starting with `'$'` and extract the word:

```
[word[1:] for line in s.split('\n') for word in line.split() if word.startswith('$') and len(word) > 1]
```

where `s` is your paragraph.

which outputs:

```
['2000']
```

Comment: how to remove $ from array?

Comment: You need `['2000']` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that (provided input is the string you wrote above)-

```
price_start = input.find('$')
price = input[price_start:].split(' ')[0]
```

**IF** there is only 1 occurrence like you said.

Alternative- you could use regex like that-

```
price = re.findall('\S*\$\S*\d', input)[0]
price = price.replace('$', '')
```

Comment: how to remove $ from array?

Comment: what do you mean? @MohammadNurdin

Comment: I only requires the number, ignore the $

Comment: price = price.replace('$', '')
I updated the answer (:

Answer (score 0):

Since this is very simple you don't need a regex solution, this should sufice:

```py
words = text.split()
words_with_dollar = [word for word in words if '$' in word]
print(words_with_dollar)

>>> ['$', '$2000']
```

If you don't want the dollar sign alone, you can add a filter like this:

```py
words_with_dollar = [word for word in words if '$' in word and '$' != word]
print(words_with_dollar)

>>> ['$2000']
```

Comment: how to remove $ from array?

Comment: @MohammadNurdin you can add an `if` condition in the `list comprehension`, the 2nd version is read like this: if the string `$` is inside the `word` and the `word` is not equal to `$` then append it to the list.